# "Academic interest" implementation of a Finite State Machine

Tags: mathematics, typescript, state-machine

## Context

I'm playing around the concept of a [Finite State Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). While I understand the basic principles behind it, I want to implement a simple, yet generic class which could be reused in the future projects.

## Focus

The code below intentionally separates the `StateMachineDefinition` and `StateMachineRuntime` interfaces from the `StateMachine` class which implements them. This is done in order to distinct the `initialState` from the `currentState` of a given instance of the state machine. This also allows providing the minimum necessary information about the state machine when it's being constructed. In other words, this separation is on purpose.

What I want help with, are a few things I either don't like or don't know:

1. Explicitly specifying `... | undefined` to make the compiler happy is ugly! E.g.

   ```
   const currentStateAllowedTransitions: { [_ in Signal]?: State; } | undefined =
     this.transitions[this.currentState]
   ```

   and

   ```
   const newState: State | undefined = currentStateAllowedTransitions[signal];
   ```
2. Manual field copying in `StateMachine`'s constructor (from the definition provided) seems silly, especially knowing that `StateMachine` ***IS*** a `StateMachineDefinition`:

   ```
   this.states = stateMachineDefinition.states;
   this.initialState = stateMachineDefinition.initialState;
   this.finalStates = stateMachineDefinition.finalStates;
   this.transitions = stateMachineDefinition.transitions;

   this.currentState = stateMachineDefinition.initialState;
   ```
3. *Probably, not really a question for CodeReview*. In my code the `finalStates` are not really used (only allow checking whether the state machine `isInFinalState()`). What is it used in real life situations? Should I drop it altogether? Or should I change it?
4. Any other advice regarding code readability, maintainability, idiomatic TypeScript, etc are very welcome too.

## The code

**State machine's interfaces**

```
// tslint:disable:no-console

export interface StateMachineDefinition<State extends string, Signal extends string> {
  states: State[];
  initialState: State;
  finalStates: State[];
  transitions: { [state in State]?: { [signal in Signal]?: State; } };
}

export interface StateMachineRuntime<State extends string, Signal extends string> {
  currentState: State;
  process(signal: Signal): void;
  isInFinalState(): boolean;
}

type Stream<Signal> = Signal[];
```

**State machine itself**

```
export class StateMachine<State extends string, Signal extends string>
  implements
    StateMachineDefinition<State, Signal>,
    StateMachineRuntime<State, Signal> {

  states: State[] = [];
  initialState: State;
  finalStates: State[] = [];
  transitions: { [state in State]?: { [signal in Signal]?: State; } };

  currentState: State;

  constructor(stateMachineDefinition: StateMachineDefinition<State, Signal>) {
    this.states = stateMachineDefinition.states;
    this.initialState = stateMachineDefinition.initialState;
    this.finalStates = stateMachineDefinition.finalStates;
    this.transitions = stateMachineDefinition.transitions;

    this.currentState = stateMachineDefinition.initialState;

    console.info(`Initialized state machine.\n${ JSON.stringify(this, null, 2) }`);
  }

  process(signal: Signal): void {
    const currentStateAllowedTransitions: { [_ in Signal]?: State; } | undefined =
      this.transitions[this.currentState];

    if (currentStateAllowedTransitions == null) {
      throw new Error(`No transitions are allowed from '${this.currentState}'`);
    }

    const newState: State | undefined = currentStateAllowedTransitions[signal];
    if (newState == null) {
      throw new Error(`No transition is allowed from '${this.currentState}' for '${signal}'`);
    }

    this.currentState = newState;
  }

  isInFinalState(): boolean {
    return this.finalStates.some(knownFinalState => knownFinalState === this.currentState);
  }

}
```

**Example of consumption**

```
type DeviceStates = 'off' | 'waiting' | 'sleeping';
type UserCommands = 'turnOn' | 'turnOff' | 'putToSleep' | 'awake';

const stateMachine = new StateMachine<DeviceStates, UserCommands>({
  states: ['off', 'waiting', 'sleeping'],
  initialState: 'off',
  finalStates: ['off'],
  transitions: {
    off: {
      turnOn: 'waiting',
    },
    waiting: {
      turnOff: 'off',
      putToSleep: 'sleeping',
    },
    sleeping: {
      awake: 'waiting',
    },
  },
});

console.warn(`====================================`);

const signals: Stream<UserCommands> = [ 'turnOn', 'putToSleep', 'awake', 'turnOff' ];

console.warn(`original state: '${ stateMachine.currentState }'`);
console.warn(`------------------------------------`);

signals.forEach(signal => {
  const state = stateMachine.currentState;

  stateMachine.process(signal);

  console.warn(`state '${ state }' + signal '${ signal }' => state '${ stateMachine.currentState }'`);
});

console.warn(`------------------------------------`);
console.warn(`result state: '${ stateMachine.currentState }'`);
```

**Output**

> ```
> Initialized state machine.                               
> {                                                        
>   "states": [                                            
>     "off",                                               
>     "waiting",                                           
>     "sleeping"                                           
>   ],                                                     
>   "finalStates": [                                       
>     "off"                                                
>   ],                                                     
>   "initialState": "off",                                 
>   "transitions": {                                       
>     "off": {                                             
>       "turnOn": "waiting"                                
>     },                                                   
>     "waiting": {                                         
>       "turnOff": "off",                                  
>       "putToSleep": "sleeping"                           
>     },                                                   
>     "sleeping": {                                        
>       "awake": "waiting"                                 
>     }                                                    
>   },                                                     
>   "currentState": "off"                                  
> }                                                        
> ====================================                     
> original state: 'off'                                    
> ------------------------------------                     
> state 'off' + signal 'turnOn' => state 'waiting'         
> state 'waiting' + signal 'putToSleep' => state 'sleeping'
> state 'sleeping' + signal 'awake' => state 'waiting'     
> state 'waiting' + signal 'turnOff' => state 'off'        
> ------------------------------------                     
> result state: 'off'
> ```

Comment: Not enough for a full answer: **1.** Use `type State = string;` and `type Signal = number;` instead of redefining them every time. **2.** Use enums for `DeviceStates` and `UserCommands`.

Comment: @BenjaminPhilippe I did try to use `type`s but was getting compilation errors. So, feel free to post a full answer which shows how to apply both of your suggestions. As far as using `number` for `Signal` type goes, I'd not use that because `string` is a less restrictive interface. I don't want to limit clients to using numeric signals only...

Comment: Yeah, after reading your code I forgot `Signal` was supposed to be a `string`. To use `type`, just `type Something = number;` and `var thing: Something = 0;`.

Comment: @BenjaminPhilippe I know how to define a `type`. I don't understand how to apply `type` here to improve my code. I encourage you to write an answer (if you have time and desire of course). That will help me understand the improvement. So far, my attempts result in either getting compilation errors, or repeating similar code with no visible gains. This file in my GitHub repo can work as a starting point for you. It exactly matches code in my question: https://github.com/another-guy/playground/blob/master/src/finite-state-machine.ts

Comment: @BenjaminPhilippe Don't want to be "pushy"... I just wanted to say that the topic of `type` thing and the way it works with TS type inference is not widely understood in the team I work with. We would really appreciate your input on this.

Comment: If you know c or c++, `type Thing = number;` is like c/c++ `typedef int Thing;` *(or even `#define Thing int`)*. It's kinda like every time the compiler sees `Thing`, it replaces it with `number`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69716/discussion-between-igor-soloydenko-and-benjamin-philippe).